# Stop subscription when an error occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-replication

In SQL Server 2000, if an error occurs, the subscription stops and I receive an e-mail with log error. But, with SQL Server 2008, the subscription still running after error and I don't receive any e-mail.

There's a way to stop like in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2005 replication is desgined to keep retrying until a certain number of failures to overcome transient errors.

Your best way to "fix" this behavior is to locate the job in the job folder, right click on it, go to steps, double click on run agent, and then go to the advanced tab. Change Retry attemps from 2147483647 to 0.

Accept all defaults and restart your agent.

You can also access the job by locating your publication in replication monitor, locate the subscription in the right hand pane, select view details, and then select Action and Distribution Agent properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, after a "...has too many arguments specified" error, it still running :(

Comment: What has happened here is that somehow there is a schema mismatch between your replication stored procedure and the commands in the distribution database.

While you can hack this replication stored procedure to make it fit the number of commands being passed to in in the distribution database - use profiler or sp_browsereplcmds to figure that out, it might be easier to just reinitialize that particular article. use sp_dropsubscription PublicationName, ProblemTableName, SubscriberServerName, subscriberDBName

And then add it back using sp_addsubscription, or sp_refreshsubscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you are complaining about a specific error and not a general one.

You should have the name of a stored procedure.

use profiler to find the exact stored procedure call which is generating the error and then modify it for the stored procedure parameter. You may need to add or drop a parameter.

At this point you are probably best off to drop the problem article from the subscription and then add it back in.

This should respanshot just that article and send it down to the subscriber again.